# How to get deleted events on an Android calendar?

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-calendar

At the moment, I am working on a calendar SyncAdapter.
I had no problem in creating a new calendar associated with an existing account or creating event so this part is working fine.
I also achieved detecting new/modified events on the client side by using the DIRTY flag defined on CalendarContract.Events.

However, when it comes to deletion, I encounter a big difficulty:
When I suppress an event through the android calendar app, it seemingly do not just set the DELETED flag to 1 but actually completely removes the event.
Is there any way I can know when an event is deleted this way, since I need to inform the server about the event deletion ?

Thanks for you time and sorry for this clumsy first post on stackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my problem:
The event is completely deleted by the calendar application in the case where you did not put a value in the CalendarContract.Events._SYNC_ID field of the event.
I hope it will maybe help someone else having the same problem.